# Jasmine passes tests that throw exceptions

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I am testing javascript code that throws an exception (temporarily, early TDD state) but jasmine passes the test.

Is there any way to set up jasmine such that it fails with an unexpected exception?

Are there other javascript unit test frameworks that do not pass such tests?

Comment: Can you please include the relevant code?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you are using the latest version 1.2.0.
The code bellows fails:

```
describe("must fail on error", function(){
  it("a + 1 should produce an error", function(){
    expect(a + 1).toEqual(2);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I stumbled on this post searching for something else related to Jasmine testing. Before seeing this question, I saw this a blog post on [testing exceptions with Jasmine](http://www.ecofic.com/about/blog/testing-for-exceptions-with-jasmine). In that post, the author uses the `bind` command like this:

```
it('should allow us pass in parameters', function () {
  expect(myOtherProcedure.bind(null, 10, 'you generated: ')).not.toThrow();
});
```